# Flash, ActionScript 3: get all movieclips that are containing in a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, for-loop, iteration

Lest just say i have a movieClip A which contains movieClips B1,B2,B3,B4,B5

I write code in A to receive all movieclips that a contains and like print there name.

i tried this with no succes:

```
for each (a:MovieClip in this)
    trace(a.name);
```

does anyone know how to get this working.

** note the trace name is actually an example i want to do very different things with the objects itself like changing there visibility and such **

thanks,
Matthy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're trying to do, but you could do something like this to pull their instance names from a parent movielcip:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < target_mc.numChildren; i++) {
trace (target_mc.getChildAt(i).name);
}
```

You can also pull out more information such as the type of object with something a little more verbose:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < target_mc.numChildren; i++) {
trace ('\t|\t ' +i+'.\t name:' + target_mc.getChildAt(i).name + '\t type:' + typeof 
(target_mc.getChildAt(i))+ '\t' + target_mc.getChildAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mc:MovieClip;
for each(mc in this) trace(mc);
```

You just needed to declare the variable outside the statement.